# How to disable xdebug on command line window?

Tags: laravel, xdebug

Anybody know how to disable the xdebug when run command on cmd? I got it run every time like the below:

[image]

I have no idea about it.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What you really should be doing is to update your version of xdebug. Disabling it is not the answer.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it now. Change some line inside php.ini. I have not used xdebug before, so I have no idea about it. Thanks for your answer. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you need to comment the respective line in your php.ini.
You can find which php.ini you are using like this

```
php -i
```

or, on unix-like systems (a lot easier)

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

then you look for something like this inside your php.ini:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File => D:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Now you know where is your php.ini and then you can edit it. Look for the line:

```
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

and comment it with ; ( like `;zend_extension` )